# How to get the value of closest SPAN?

Tags: javascript, jquery, localization

I have created a registration form and now I am trying to put null validations on the fields.
All fields are location inside one table like :

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="5" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="50%" valign="top">
                <span id="ctl00_PageBody_lblFname">Prénom</span>
                <strong><font color="#FF0000">*</font></strong><br />
                <input name="ctl00$PageBody$txtFname" type="text" id="ctl00_PageBody_txtFname" rel="First Name" />

                <br />

                <span id="ctl00_PageBody_lblLname">Nom</span>
                <strong><font color="#FF0000">*</font></strong><br />
                <input name="ctl00$PageBody$txtLname" type="text" id="ctl00_PageBody_txtLname" rel="Last Name" />
             </td>
         </tr>
</table>
```

Now using jquery I am trying to create a generic function which iterates through all the text boxes and if they are empty it displays a message mentioning the Field Name :

```
        var Msg = "Please provide values for :";
        var nullFieldTracked = 'false';

        $('input[type="text"], select').each(function () {
            if (this.value == '' && this.hasAttribute("rel")) {
                nullFieldTracked = 'true';
                Msg += '\n - ' + $(this).attr('rel');
            }
        });
        if (nullFieldTracked == 'true') {
            alert(Msg);
            return false;
        }
```

Code works like charm, I have added a 'rel' attribute to the textboxes in order to read the Field Name, BUT

Now there is a change in the requirement and I need to launch this website in multipul languages and hence it will read the attributes from the resource files and asp.net doesn't create a meta resource for 'rel' tag, So I am thinking to reading the Field Name from the closest Span, but not able to Track.

Kindly help with Jquery.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: wow, `<font>` tags ... anyway just find the parent `<td>` and then descend to find the first `<span>`

Comment: @Pointy should it be migrated to `museum.stackexchange.com`... ?

Comment: On a general note, the following has been depricated in favour of css. The `width` attribute of `<td>` and the `font`/`color` attributes.

Comment: @Pointy <font> tag is there just to highlight a red *, to indicate them as mandatory, you can suggest any other work around, i don't mind.

Comment: @VishalSachdeva `<strong style='color: red'>*</strong>` - `<font>` tags are deprecated and really have been obsolete for 10 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retreive value from closest span

```
$(this).prevAll("span").first().text()
```

Comment: That won't work if the `<input>` is not a child element of the `<span>` (and, in this case apparently, they are not)

Comment: Works like a charm :) thanks, so .preAll('span').first() starts searching from the bottom to top, isit ??

Comment: since its Span, the val() wouldn't support, use .html() or text() instead.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you can add data-attribute in your text field in .net

If yes,
you can store span's id in `data` attribute of input that will have.each text field should save span id in his data attribute like

```
                <input name="ctl00$PageBody$txtFname" type="text" id="ctl00_PageBody_txtFname" rel="First Name" data-error-span = '#span1'/>
```

now in your JS

```
$('input[type="text"], select').each(function () {
        if (this.value == '' && this.hasAttribute("rel")) {
            nullFieldTracked = 'true';
            Msg += '\n - ' + $($(this).data('error-span')).val();
        }
    });
```

another option could be to store error in data attribute 
then JS would be

```
Msg += '\n - ' +  $(this).data('error-message');
```

which also looks readable

Awesome Rails :)

Comment: data attribute, If I am not wrong belongs ti HTML5 and I am I not actually using that.

Answer (score 0):

Use .closest()
this gives nearest selector element.